# Python: How to plot circles around given coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I'm currently trying to plot circles of a given radius around coordinates, in order to see if the plotted circles overlap. I currently have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(len(b)):
    for j in range(len(d)):

        circle1=plt.Circle((b[i,0], b[i,1]), 0.5, color='r', fill=False)
        circle1=plt.Circle((d[j,0], d[j,1]), 0.5, color='g', fill=False)
        fig = plt.gcf()
        fig.gca().add_artist(circle1)
        fig.gca().add_artist(circle2)
        fig.savefig('plotcircles.png')
```

b and d are lists with two elements per row.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your circle plotting code saves len(d) x len(b) images with the same name, and these images have more and more circles (as you are only creating a new image once, implicilty at `plt.gcf()`). If you just want to create many png images, I suggest you draw the two circles once and then every round just change their position by using their `center` property.

However, if you only want to know if two circes overlap, there are much easier methods. You need the distance between the centers (*s*) of the circles and the radii of the two circles (*r1*, *r2*). If *r1* + *r2* < *s*, the circles overlap. Calculating the overlapping area is also rather straightforward with these three numbers.